# How to multiply the value in df_a by the values in df_b, take the sum of these values, and append them together for all values in df_a?

Tags: python, pandas

I would like to multiply the value in one dataframe (df_a) by the values in another dataframe (df_b) and then take the sum of these values, and append them together for all values in df_a. E.g.
df_a:

| col_x |
| --- |
| 10 |
| 20 |

and df_b:

| col_y |
| --- |
| 5 |
| 6 |

Would result in:
[(10 x 5) + (10 x 6), (20 x 5) + (20 x 6)] or [110, 220]

I think this can be done in a for loop:

```
for x, y in zip(df_a, df_b):
    i = sum(x * y)
    a.append(i)
```

But this throws an error for float object not being iterable.

Comment: What have you tried, and what went wrong with your attempts?

Comment: for x, y in zip(df_a, df_b):
    i = sum(x * y)
    a.append(i) -- but it throws an error for float object not being iterable

Answer (score 1):

No need for complicated loops or broadcasting. `(10 x 5) + (10 x 6)` is equal to `10*(5+6)`. So first sum the second Series, then multiply the first one with this scalar.

```
out = df_a['col_x']*df_b['col_y'].sum()
```

Output:

```
0    110
1    220
Name: col_x, dtype: int64
```

As array:

```
out = df_a['col_x'].to_numpy()*df_b['col_y'].sum()
```

Output: `array([110, 220])`

Alternative with an outer product:

```
import numpy as np
np.outer(df_a['col_x'], df_b['col_y']).sum(axis=1)
```

Output: `array([110, 220])`

Answer (score 1):

Perfect job for numpy broadcasting:

```py
x = df_a["col_x"].to_numpy()
y = df_b["col_y"].to_numpy()[:, None]

(x * y).sum(axis=0)
```

Answer (score 0):

Why are you using dataframes with one column when you are actually using them as arrays?  Just use `numpy`:

```
a = np.array([10, 20])
b = np.array([5, 6])
np.matmul(a, b) + np.matmul(a, b[::-1])
# 330
```